# Java: Ignored RuntimeException with ScheduledExecutorService

Tags: java, schedule

### Introduction

I'm currently working on a project that logs data from a website to a database every x hours.

But when the database connection properties are not good, the program does not throw a `RuntimeException` pretends everything is fine.

#### the goal

When the schedule has a `RuntimeException` (configuration or connection to database exceptions), I have to stop the whole program and tell the user about the exception.

### My code:

```java
    private static ScheduledExecutorService executeWithPeriod(Runnable runnable, int period) {
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        executor.schedule(runnable, Math.max(1, period), TimeUnit.HOURS);
        return executor;
    }
```

**The `runnable` takes care of getting data and saving it to the database.**

### The possible throwed `RuntimeException`:

- DockerSecretVariableNotFoundException
- EnvironmentVariableNotFoundException

*All these exceptions extends `RuntimeException`*

Someone have the solution to throws the `RuntimeException` to the main thread ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just throw a RuntimeException? How would you expect the framework to react to that?

Comment: Your question is not answerable. It boils down to, "How can I catch an exception right now when it won't be thrown until my code is executed at a later, scheduled time?" The main thread would have to block, and then there's no point in scheduling. Voting to close.

Comment: If you interpret this as the timing issue since execution is asynchronous, a java.util.concurrency.Future might help. If you close the question we cannot even discuss that.

Comment: @erickson Thank you for your feedback I improved my question.

Comment: That helps, since it shows you are using a recurring schedule, not a one-shot. But it doesn't explain what you want your main thread to be doing until an exception is thrown. Is it waiting? Doing other work? Why does the main thread need to be notified? Why not handle the exception in the scheduled task? Without some more information along these lines, we can't give a useful answer.

Comment: @erickson 
When we have a `RuntimeException` from the schedule, I have to stop the whole program and tell the user about the problem.
The possible problem is invalid variable environment or a invalid properties from docker secret.

Comment: you can call the `get()` method of `ScheduledFuture` returned by `schedule` - it should throw an `ExecutionException` if the task threw an Exception (but hard to understand what the real problem or use case is)

Comment: What is your goal? Do you *want* other threads to handle those exceptions that occur on this background thread? I'm voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't demonstrated a need for multiple threads, so you can eliminate the complexity of signaling between concurrent threads. Use a single thread instead:

```java
final class YourTask {

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
        YourTask task = new YourTask();
        while (true) {
            try {
                task.doYourThing();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
            TimeUnit.HOURS.sleep(1L);
        }
    }

    private void doYourThing() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("I'm saving data from a website to a database!");
        throw new RuntimeException("Oh no! I can't read my configuration!");
    }

}
```

Note that this solution "tells the user about the problem" and "stops the whole program," as specified.

Comment: I had used this solution to avoid using thread.sleep because I was told it was not recommended.
Thank you for your answer !

Comment: I don't recommend having a thread sleep while other threads in the process are doing work; it would be good to find a way to have all threads helping. But if your program doesn't have anything else to do, it's okay to `sleep()`.

Comment: Indeed in my case the thread.sleep is the best thing.
Although I would have liked to have the solution with `java.util.concurrency.Future` to make the code of the program more scalable to possible modification.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the task is just to tnrow a RuntimeException, how about this?

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        throw new RuntimeException("mark my words");
    }
}
```

Rest assured this code throws an exception. You can try using this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyRunnable().run();
}
```

However usually Runnables are run in their own thread:

```
new Thread(new MyRunnable()).start()
```

So now the exception is thrown as well. However it terminates the thread - and that's it.

I am coming back to my question from the comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Hiran, but in the project I need to use a schedule to save regularly data to a database.